# "DoS" protection by default on Linux

Tags: linux

Given that, by default, neither `iptables` nor `ufw` nor `selinux` nor `apparmor` are enabled, is there any built-in feature (maybe a sys parameter?) blocking TCP connections from an IP when a certain number of connections is reached?

I'm not aware of any, but a coworker is convinced that somehow the OS is blocking connections.

FWIW, we're establishing WebRTC connections using Seleniums.

Answer (score 0):

The sort and simple answer is: "no"

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: uuh - how? There is none and thats it.